my firewall rule is evaluated before my firewall policy in gcp
I have configured a vpc with firewall rules and firewall policy. When I try to connect to resources in the VPC, my traffic matches the firewall rule with priority 1000 and it doesn't match my firewall policy with priority 100. How does it work? are firewall rules evaluated before firewall policies?

Based on docs, it seems VPC firewall rule are evaluated before the global network firewall policy.
The priority number is ranging 0 to 65535, the lower integer indicates higher prio.

Thank you for the response and the link to the doc, it helps. :)
